# Was this Rogue One love story originally intended?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

At the very end of Rogue One we see Jyn and Cassian

> …have what appears to be a falling in love moment moments before they die.

Was this story intended the entire time, or was it part of the reshoots they did? It seems kind of shoehorned in at the end here, and wonder if in the reshoots they cut other scenes that lead up to this.

Comment: It was originally intended, together with discussions of sand being uncomfortable. Then Christopher McQuarrie  came in and said "ewwww cooties!" and trimmed it down to understated looks.

Comment: More seriously: no info I was able to find, but it's almost certain Jyn and Cassian were intended to live until Story Group Vaderized that idea, which makes the romantic interest possibility not-unlikely. But to be honest, until someone leakes/publishes early script (maybe Making Of... book?), we won't know.

Comment: @DVK ah one of those, we may never know for sure /sigh lol.

Comment: I'd think that after going through the stress and fear of the mission and having mere moments before annihilation, most people would turn to each other in comfort in a quasi-romantic stance. Also, both *were* brave, clever, resolute, and hot: there was almost certainly some kind of attraction going on, even if it had never got anywhere even if they had had time.

Comment: Han and Leia were far more antagonistic in A New Hope. It seemed like the same kind of relationship to me.

Comment: @T.E.D. - not really. Han never had a full, complete assurance that Leia was likely to try and kill him because he was planning to kill Bail Organa (which was exactly the dynamics between Jyn and Cassian)

Comment: I assumed they would fall in love based on how they didn't like each other when they first met and he even lied to her. That's the makings of a movie romance, and I'd have been *very* surprised if they didn't get together at the end.

Comment: It seems like everyone is staying mum about production changes while the movie is in theaters. Maybe after a few years of home video sales people will feel more chatty about this or a DVD extra will be created that talks about it.

Answer (score 2):

There's definitely a bit of affection between it's not imagined but Rouge one takes place over such a short time frame, I imagine it to 2 days or less maybe someone knows exactly, that if they did manage to fall in love or even stopped for a kiss anyone else would have be like we do not have time for romance right now.

I think the reshoots took out the story line rather than added it as the official cut has them separated on Scarif for a period where as there are pre reshoots scenes of them back on the beach with the plans running so it seemed that ending kept them together longer or throughout assuming they had to upload the plans back on the beach or try to fly off planet with them.

I think Gareth Edwards said he originally didn't think they could go through with killing everyone so the pre reshoots might have ended with them making it off planet with plans.

Answer (score -4):

They didn't fall in love. Otherwise, it would have been a kiss instead. Thankfully, they left any love story out. It would have been out of place, and just confused everyone at the end, as there was 0 romantic chemistry between the 2. The holding hands was just to comfort each other that death was coming, and they could only find solace in holding someone's hand. Think of it-what if it was you and some girl who are about to die like that. Wouldn't you want some kind of help?

Answer (score -6):

It definitely was, or at least, was meant to be before the reshoots. There was something hinted between Jyn and Cassian. It's most blatant when he says to her "welcome home" and they share a little moment, and then most of the ending of the movie between the two. The ending where they're both sitting on a beach, embracing under a "sunset" also hints that there is something between them.